# Use regular v-data-table layout in mobile version

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I've created a v-data-table, the behavior that is expected is not to put all the headers for every row of the table, (by default vuetify render as I said) I show the actual behavior:

[image: this is how vuetify show the v-data-table by default]

What I need is to show the v-data-table headers as it does in normal size, one row for headers and the rest for items of the v-data-table. Any approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Vuetify 2, right? Have a look at the [`:mobile-breakpoint`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-mobile-breakpoint) property, set it to `0` to disable mobile display:

```html
<v-data-table
  :mobile-breakpoint="0"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: it works¡ please could you vote up my question?